# Enable datacursormode on by default

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

The new version of MATLAB (2019b) seems to have changed the data cursor functionality in a way that complicates user interaction.

In old version it was possible to click a graph or image and see the value.

Now I need to run the following command to get back this functionality.

```
datacursormode on
```

Is there a way to get this back by default?

Comment: Put it in your [`startup` file](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/startup.html)?

Comment: @LuisMendo any `clc; clear all` would nuke it

Comment: Sorry, I don’t know how `datacursormode` works. So it has to be done for each figure? If that’s the case, maybe include that command in the `DefaultFigureCreateFcn` property of the `groot` object, so that it applies by default to any figure